# Flexible addons for Solr to achieve sorting and filtering

Tags: views, search

My requirement is to provide end user with an option to sort/filter the search results. This can be achieved different ways but I am unclear to choose one. I found these methods.

1. Using facetapi - I can filter results, not sure about sorting.
2. Using apachesolr_sort - I can group/sort results, not sure about filtering.
3. Using apachesolr_views - I can show my results more flexible this way. But this doesn't seem to support sorting https://www.drupal.org/node/443410.
4. Using search_api and search_api_solr - This method is more preferred and flexible to group/filter/sort results. But I am worried about heavy size of these modules.

Can someone suggest me to achieve the most flexible (and less resource consuming) method of sorting/filtering results by any combination of the above modules.

Thanks!

Comment: #4 is the most extensible route. It will get your the best search experience, especially when combined with Facets API. The size of the module doesn't really have anything to do with performance. Look how enormous Views is!

Answer (score 1):

[Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) includes Views integration out of the box. Definitely you will need [Facets Api](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi). this combination is the best for Solr integration with Drupal. Here is a great [screen-cast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rArRwp_1h8Q) that might help.

Comment: Thank you.
I finally decided to use apachesolr, facetapi, search_api, search_api_solr.. @Brady's comment to my question is also helpful.
(And sorry I'm unable to upvote your answer. I'm a beginner.)

Comment: you are welcome, I think you can accept the answer because you are the question owner. anyway glad I could help.